# VBA: variable name = type name?

Tags: vba

Consider

```
Type Country
    ...
End Type

Type Ambassador
    Country As Country
End Type
```

Is this a problem in VBA? As you can see, the ambassador needs a country, which has the same name as its type. Is this an issue? If yes, what are the recommended workaround?

Comment: No, it's not an issue but you will have to fully qualify it when you call it: `Ambassador.Country.[...]`

Comment: In addition to @KostasK. 's answer, you could use a naming convention for your user defined types.  I always prefixed mine with udt; so udtCountry and udtAmbassador for the type names.  Further I'd use prefix u for an instance of an udt type.  So for example `Dim uGermany as udtCountry`.   In other words naming conventions help you avoid naming clashes.